# ax not defined in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a problem with Matplotlib. I have just copied and pasted a block from a Jupyter notebook that I previously made for a plot with two curves in it. In the previous Jupyter notebook everything works but in the new one I get an error message telling ''name 'ax' is not defined'. Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline




ax.plot(hours, load, color="goldenrod",drawstyle="steps-post",  linewidth=3)
load = [0, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 665, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500,0,2500, 2366, 250, 250, 373, 2500,0, 2500, 0, 2500,250, 0]    
temperature = [21, 21.6, 22, 21.3, 20.8, 20.4, 20.1, 20, 20.6, 21.1, 21.5, 21.8, 22, 21.4, 20.9, 20.5, 20.2, 20, 20.7, 21.2, 21.6, 21.9, 22, 21]

hours = list(range(25)) # [0, 1, 2, ... 22, 23, 24]
labels = [f'{h:02d}:00' for h in hours] # ["00:00", "01:00", ... "23:00", "24:00"]

fig, ax = plt.figure(linewidth=1, figsize=(9, 5))
ax = plt.gca()


ax.plot(hours, load, color="gold",drawstyle="steps-post",  linewidth=3, alpha=.8, label = 'Electrical power') # <- drawstyle argument.
ax.set_xlabel("Time of day", fontsize=16, labelpad=8)
ax.set_ylabel("Electrical power in W", fontsize=14, labelpad=8)
ax.set_xlim(0, 24)
ax.set_ylim(0, 3000)    
plt.xticks(hours, labels=labels, rotation=90)
plt.grid(axis='y', alpha=.4)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=14)

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(hours, temperature, color="red",  linewidth=3, label = 'Temperature')
ax2.set_ylabel("Temperature in °C", fontsize=14, labelpad=8)
ax2.set_ylim(20, 22.5)  
ax2.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=14)


fig = plt.gcf()
fig.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(0.25, 1.03), fontsize=14, ncol=3)
fig.tight_layout()
for item in [fig, ax]:
    item.patch.set_visible(False)
fig.savefig('ControlStrategy_Conventional.png',
        edgecolor='black', dpi=400, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

Can anyone tell me why it is not working? I'd appreciate every input.

Comment: `ax.plot(hours, load, color="goldenrod",drawstyle="steps-post",  linewidth=3)` is in the wrong spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made some adjustments on your code (below):

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

hours = list(range(24)) # [0, 1, 2, ... 22, 23, 24]
labels = [f'{h:02d}:00' for h in hours] # ["00:00", "01:00", ... "23:00", "24:00"]

load = [0, 250, 250, 250, 250, 250, 665, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500,0,2500, 2366, 250, 250, 373, 2500,0, 2500, 0, 2500,250, 0]    
temperature = [21, 21.6, 22, 21.3, 20.8, 20.4, 20.1, 20, 20.6, 21.1, 21.5, 21.8, 22, 21.4, 20.9, 20.5, 20.2, 20, 20.7, 21.2, 21.6, 21.9, 22, 21]

plt.figure(linewidth=1, figsize=(9, 5))
ax = plt.gca()

ax.plot(hours, load[0:24], color="goldenrod",drawstyle="steps-post",  linewidth=3)

ax.plot(hours, load[0:24], color="gold",drawstyle="steps-post",  linewidth=3, alpha=.8, label = 'Electrical power') # <- drawstyle argument.
ax.set_xlabel("Time of day", fontsize=16, labelpad=8)
ax.set_ylabel("Electrical power in W", fontsize=14, labelpad=8)
ax.set_xlim(0, 24)
ax.set_ylim(0, 3000)    
plt.xticks(hours, labels=labels, rotation=90)
plt.grid(axis='y', alpha=.4)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=14)

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(hours, temperature, color="red",  linewidth=3, label = 'Temperature')
ax2.set_ylabel("Temperature in °C", fontsize=14, labelpad=8)
ax2.set_ylim(20, 22.5)  
ax2.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=14)

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(0.25, 1.03), fontsize=14, ncol=3)
fig.tight_layout()
ax.patch.set_visible(False)
fig.savefig('ControlStrategy_Conventional.png', edgecolor='black', dpi=400, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

And it generated the following output:

[image]

Modifications:

- hours had 25 entries, not 24. Not sure exactly what is your intent,
  but to with 0 and 24 (25 entries) you are representing more than 1
  day;
- considered 24 values for the load variable as well. Labels and temperature have 24 values only by definition;
- changed the order of defining the variables hours, labels, load and temperature;
- changed the call to the plt.figure, to store only the axis;
- removed the for loop at the end;

Comment: Why are you assigning the output of `plt.figure`?

Comment: Indeed, it is not necessary. I used less intervention possible to make it to work. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Daniel. I would like to change the axis. The temperature should be on the right hand side and the load left because I would like to see horizontal lines for the temperature values e.g. 22°C. How can I change this? I tried it but the plot looks not correct

Comment: I just use the code in the middle of the program:
ax.plot(hours, load[0:24], color="gold",drawstyle="steps-post",  linewidth=3, alpha=.8, label = 'Electrical power') # <- drawstyle argument.
ax.set_xlabel("Time of day", fontsize=16, labelpad=8)
ax.set_ylabel("Temperature in °C", fontsize=14, labelpad=8)
ax.set_xlim(0, 24)
ax.set_ylim(20, 22)    
plt.xticks(hours, labels=labels, rotation=90)
plt.grid(axis='y', alpha=.4)
ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=14)

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(hours, load, color="red",  linewidth=3, label = 'Load')